# Determine if .deb package is installed using Bash

Tags: bash, linux

I was able to use dpkg-query to determine if a package is installed on Ubuntu, but it's a bit of a mess because the name used to install the package doesn't always align with what it's installed as. For instance, `gnutls-dev` is installed under `libgnutls-dev`...

Any suggestions on how I could clean this up a bit?

```
function isInstalled() {
    if dpkg-query -W -f'${Status}' "$1" 2>/dev/null | grep -q "ok installed" || dpkg-query -W -f'${Status}' "lib$1" 2>/dev/null | grep -q "ok installed"; then
        echo 1;
    fi

    echo 0
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you install using a name that the actual package `Provides`?  So that a different package is installed than what was requested?

Comment: I'm saying if you run `apt install gnutls-dev` it's installed but is listed by `dpkg-query` as `libgnutls-dev`... `gnutls-dev` is a virtual package, I guess. But either way, the code essentially does what it needs to for the sake of my project, just curious if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: What's the intended usage? Where would you get the package name to test?

Comment: Using it as part of a custom install script, package names are hard-coded into the script. Just using this function as a way of adding a visual indicator for which of the required dependencies are already installed or need to be installed.

Answer (score 3):

It seems odd that the function prints `0` in all cases, including when `1` has been printed.

For a utility like this, it's probably better to communicate via the exit status:

```
isInstalled() {
    !   dpkg-query -W -f'${Status}' "$1" 2>/dev/null | grep -q "ok installed" \
     || dpkg-query -W -f'${Status}' "lib$1" 2>/dev/null | grep -q "ok installed"
}
```

I'd be inclined to remove the `!`, returning zero (success) if the package is found.

If you have `aptitude` available, it's possible to ask it to search for any installed package of the given name, or providing the name:

```
aptitude -q2 search "~i~P?exact-name($1)|~i?exact-name($1)" >/dev/null
```

- `~i`: installed package
- `~P`: provides name
- `|`: alternation
- `^$1\$`
- `?exact-name`: exactly what it says

This is less brittle, as it doesn't rely on the providing package being formed by prepending `lib` to the virtual package name.  For example, with `www-browser`, it finds all installed web browsers.  Also, it avoids matching superstrings of the supplied name.

If you know that `$1` will always be the name of a virtual package, you can of course use just the `~P` side of the alternation.

Comment: Interesting approach on using aptitude, it seems a lot more reliable... but it is significantly slower.

Comment: Yes, it does spend a lot of time rebuilding its databases; I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 2):

> the name used to install the package doesn't always align with what it's installed as. For instance, `gnutls-dev` is installed under `libgnutls-dev`

That's because they are different things:

- `gnutls-dev` is a single command/utility
- `libgnutls-dev` is a package

Note that one single package can contain various commands. I'd say the most notable cases are `coreutils` and `util-linux`.

So to check if a command or package is installed, you'd need to follow different approaches.

For example (assuming a recent version of Bash):

```
check_command() {
  local 'command' 'not_found'
  for command; do
    if ! type -- "${command}" > '/dev/null' 2>&1; then
      printf '%s\n' "Command not found: ${command}"
      (( not_found++ ))
    fi
  done
  if (( not_found > 0 )); then
    printf '%s\n' "Missing commands: ${not_found}"
    return '1'
  fi
}

check_package() {
  local 'not_found' 'package' 'packages'
  packages="$( dpkg --get-selections | cut -f '1' | sort )"
  for package; do
    if ! grep -P -e "^${package}\$" <<< "${packages}" > '/dev/null' 2>&1; then
      printf '%s\n' "Package not found: ${package}"
      (( not_found++ ))
    fi
  done
  if (( not_found > 0 )); then
    printf '%s\n' "Missing packages: ${not_found}"
    return '1'
  fi
}
```

Then:

```
# cat and lsblk are commands
# coreutils and util-linux are packages

$ check_command cat coreutils lsblk util-linux
Command not found: coreutils
Command not found: util-linux
Missing commands: 2

$ check_package cat coreutils lsblk util-linux
Package not found: cat
Package not found: lsblk
Missing packages: 2
```